# problem in citation of reference paper with theorem

Tags: bibliographies, citing

In writing of an article by using `\cite[Proposition~3.iii]{<source>}`. I got `[?, proposition 3.iii]`, and the required output is like `[12, Theorem 4.3]`. kindly suggest me the way to get it correct thanks.

Comment: Have you checked spelling? Did you run bibtex (or whatever you're using) inbetween? Every time you add a citation you have to update the references by running your bibliography handler (bibtex, biblatex, etc.) and then run Latex again.

Comment: Please tell us whether you use a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`. Please also tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: I am using cite and bibliography with \bibitem.

Answer (score 1):

I take it from your follow-up comment that you build the bibliography by hand, by providing suitably formatted `\bibitem` entries in the `thebibliography` environment. If this interpretation is correct, you need to

- provide a "key" argument for each `\bibitem` entry, e.g.,

  ```
  \bibitem{aa:2020} Anne Author, 2020, Thoughts.
  ```
- use the entry's "key" in the required argument of `\cite`, e.g.,

  ```
  \cite[Proposition~3.iii]{aa:2020}
  ```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite[Proposition~3.iii]{aa:2020}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{aa:2020} Anne Author, 2020, Thoughts.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```